# Errors from hasErrors only appear in second submit

Tags: grails

I'm trying to render some errors to the view but the errors only appear in second submit.

```
//Controller Method
def submitUserInfo = { UserDetailsCommand command ->



    if(!session.upgradeActive) {
        return upgradeProcessEnded();
    }

    User user = springSecurityService.currentUser;

    if(!user.userDetails) {

        user.userDetails = new UserDetails(params);

        user.userDetails.user = user;
    }
    else {

        user.userDetails.properties = params;
    }

    if (!command.hasErrors()) {

        if (!params.firstName)
        {
            user.userDetails.errors.rejectValue('firstName',message(code: 'base.subscription.errors.generalOutput', args: [message(code: 'base.user.firstName.label')]))
        }
        if (!params.lastName)
        {
            user.userDetails.errors.rejectValue('lastName',message(code: 'base.subscription.errors.generalOutput', args: [message(code: 'base.user.lastName.label')]))
        }

        // Internal Server Error Code
        response.status = 400
        return render (view: 'userInfo', model: [userInstance: user])
    }
    ...
}

//Class
@Validateable
class UserDetailsCommand {

    // Properties
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String phoneNumber

    //Company
    String companyName
    String companyPhoneNumber
    String address
    String postalCode
    String country
    String city
    String state

    static constraints = {
        firstName nullable: false
        lastName nullable: false
        address nullable: false
        postalCode nullable: false
        country nullable: false
        city nullable: false
        state nullable: false
        companyName nullable: false
    }
}

//View
<g:if test='${flash.message}'>
        <div class="control-group primary-background">
            <div class='alert alert-error'>
                <i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i>
                ${flash.message}
            </div>
        </div>
        <%-- Clear messages to prevent showing on refresh --%>
        ${flash.clear()}
    </g:if>
<g:hasErrors bean="${userInstance.userDetails}">
<div class="control-group primary-background">
    <p class="alert alert-error">
        <g:each var="error" in="${userInstance.userDetails.errors.allErrors}">
            <i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i>
            <g:message error="${error}" />
            <br />
        </g:each>
    </p>
</div>
</g:hasErrors>

<div class="flex_column one_half first">

<g:hiddenField name="id" value="${ userInstance?.id }"/>

<h3><g:message code="base.user.details.title" /></h3>   

<strong><g:message code="base.user.email.label" />: </strong>
${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "username")}

<label for="firstName"><g:message code="base.user.firstName.label" /></label>
<g:textField name="firstName" value="${fieldValue(bean: userInstance.userDetails, field: "firstName")}"/>

<label for="lastName"><g:message code="base.user.lastName.label" /></label>
<g:textField name="lastName" value="${fieldValue(bean: userInstance.userDetails, field: "lastName")}"/>
...
```

Well, in the first submit no errors appear after that the errors are shown.
When I change the validation rule, the blank fields,the case repeats again.
If the fields are blank in the first submit no errors appear after the second submit them appear.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Internal server error is 500 not 400...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only showing the code block for `if (!command.hasErrors()) {`

If you submit a blank `firstName` or `lastName`, it *should* have errors.

If it does not, should you maybe be using `blank: false` instead of `nullable: false` as your validator for `firstName` and `lastName` instead of trying to roll your own validation?